# How to disable auto pairing of quotes

Tags: windows, keyboard

My Windows 7 installation automatically tries to pair quotes and does a very poor job. For example, when I press the quote key before a word nothing happens, but when I move the cursor to the end of the word and press the quote key again, both quotes are inserted after the word. Basically I am unable to insert one quote and it's super annoying.

It is a windows functionality, because it happens in all programs.

How do I disable it?

Comment: What do you mean by "the quote button"?  What application(s) are you using when you see this happen?

Comment: By the quote button I mean the key on my keyboard that inserts quotes into the text...
It happens with chrome, notepad, dreamweaver and, well, every app I ever opened.

Comment: Sounds like you've got some oddball third-party software installed, perhaps something that came with the keyboard?

Comment: That's possible. I'll have a look when I get home. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I didn't find anything suspicious... any other ideas ?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/346142/my-windows-keyboard-is-being-clever-with-the-quote-keys-how-can-i-stop-it

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The problem is in the installed keyboard (windows input service).

1. In your **Control Panel** > **Region and Language** > **Keyboards and Languages** you'll most likely find **US Keyboard - International**, which is an input service that has the ugly autocomplete feature.
2. Add a new keyboard **English - US** (or Serbian or any other you like) and make it the default keyboard (in the drop down list above).
3. **Remove** the "buggy" keyboard.
4. Voila!

Hope this works for you!

Comment: also to remove it you have to first make sure it is not default (in the menu on top)

Comment: Don't forget to reboot the computer, or log off and log back in for it to take effect!

Comment: Reboot isn't mandatory for windows 8

Comment: This has to be the single most stupidest bug (ugh... I mean "feature") of Windows.

Comment: Still works as a solution in Windows 10 Pro 21H1

Answer (score 17):

If you press <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> at the same time, it will switch back to normal (like how you want it).

Comment: That was the answer !

Comment: You can remove the keyboard shortcut via `Configuratiescherm\Klok, taal en land/regio\Taal\Geavanceerde instellingen` (Control panel, clock, language, advanced) - set it to "not assigned".

Comment: that worked for me!

Answer (score 7):

I encounter this when accidentally press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>.
If you press again <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> things gone back to normal.

Comment: @kapantzak: sounds like an answer to me; the answer being that pressing control-shift a second time fixes the problem.

Comment: **CTRL + SHIFT** changes the lagnguages into your operating system, switching between the one selected as available.