# How to start in the middle of quatations marks

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, quotes

Hello I was watching a tutorial video, what I saw was that the person immidiately started in the middle of the double quotes "". (he was using a mac)

When I do the double quotes "" I always hit the back arrow to get in between the double quotes... Can I fix that? I think it is a small tweak but can make a lot of difference.

I use Atom on a windows 10.

**EDIT:** I found the solution via Superuser who linked to an other stackoverflow:
[How to disable auto pairing of quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445325/how-to-disable-auto-pairing-of-quotes)

I had to change my keyboard language to English instead of US Keyboard - international. Now when I tab the ' character once. It immidiately appears! :)

Comment: Are you typing `"` once or twice? If you type the character once, it should automatically add another one, and leave your cursor in between. If you type it twice, then it will go to the end of the second one.

Comment: I have to type it twice.. with shift and then double tab the character left from the enter button. so shortcut: SHIFT + '

Let's figure that out if it's possible to type it once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI: I did found the answer (I switched my keyboard language). It was international which will not give you the quatation marks immidiately when hit.. But now it does. Just choose another English version for you keyboard than International ;-)!

Answer (score 0):

This is default behavior in Atom 1.20.1 x64 on my Mac.  I just opened it and tried some test code and it did this automatically.

It may be a difference between Atom for Windows and Mac, I don't have Windows to test.  It is possible you have a package that affects this behavior that you could check.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. With notepad and other typing software it's also the same I have to double tab the '' (quotes) to make them visible. Still trying to figure it out.